# Vagrant does not find virtual maschine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Vagrant does not resume a suspended maschine. Instead it creates a new one everytime I "vagrant up". Running Vagrant in Debug mode gave me this:

```
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "f7974dcf-1394-421a-a1c3-bce1ef352b2f"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 2147483651
DEBUG virtualbox: VM not found! Clearing saved machine ID and reloading.
```

When I run "VBoxManage.exe showvminfo f7974dcf-1394-421a-a1c3-bce1ef352b2f", I get the data for this maschine. How do I get Vagrant to recognize and resume a maschine?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add it back to .vagrant.d/data/machine-index. I would recommend you to destroy the box using VBoxManage.exe.

```
VBoxManage.exe discardstate f7974dcf-1394-421a-a1c3-bce1ef352b2f
```

and then create a new box.

Comment: I will check if that helps. I already deleted the .vagrant,.vagrant.d and .VirtualBox folders. But vagrant up -> vagrant suspend -> vagrant up led to a recreation of the maschine again.